How to calculate the average width of linear pixel cluster in R?
Conducting some analysis on linear landscape elements (such as walls, ditches etc.) I would like to calculate the average width of each element.
The calculation is based on raster data with 1 m resolution. Most of the time I'm using the terra package.
The linear elements come as clusters of adjacent cells.
Here is a reproducible example of one linear element:
library(terra)

## make coordinates
coords_1 <- cbind(x <- c(1, 29, 25, 63, 122, 21),
                  y <- c(65, 41, 37, 31, 15, 1))
coords_2 <- cbind(x <- c(63, 89),
                  y <- c(31, 54))
coords_3 <- cbind(x <- c(21, 5),
                  y <- c(1, 11))

## make points
p1 <- terra::vect(coords_1)
p2 <- terra::vect(coords_2)
p3 <- terra::vect(coords_3)

## make polygons
l1 <- terra::buffer(terra::as.lines(p1), 2)
l2 <- terra::buffer(terra::as.lines(p2), 3)
l3 <- terra::buffer(terra::as.lines(p3), 1.5)

## aggregate polygons
l <- terra::union(terra::union(l1, l2), l3)
l <- terra::aggregate(l)

## make raster
e <- terra::rast(ext(l))
terra::res(e) <- c(1, 1) 
r <- terra::rasterize(l, e)

## plot
plot(r)

PLOT: linear pixel cluster
My idea for calculating the average width of the element was as follows:
## get the number of every non-NA pixel
cn <- terra::cells(r)

## add number of pixel as raster layer
r1 <- r %>%
  dplyr::mutate(cn = terra::cells(is.na(.)))

## calculate the amount of adjacent cells for every single cell (seperately for 8 directions)

######## ??????? ########

## add amounts for opposite directions
## get the minimum
## join the raster with the result via left_join (by = cn)

Does anybody have an idea how to do this? The terra::adjacent() function gives back the number (i.e. name) of the adjacent cells, not the amount per direction. Furthermore NA cells are also considered which is not intended in this case.
Thanks a lot in advance for your ideas!
